# Rigidbody between two terrains getting dragged to the upper one

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, terrain, rigid-bodies

If a rigidbody is below a terrain it is getting dragged up on the terrain

I have 2 terrains, one over another to make a cave like shape. If I put a rigidbody on terrain below it is getting dragged onto the terrain above. So i cant even put a single rigidbody inside that cave.

I tried with mesh collider on terrain obove instead of using terrain collider. But terrain does not have an actual mesh, so it didnt work.

Is there a solution to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Unity's TerrainCollider is [height-map based](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainCollider.html), you can't put one on top of the other and expect proper collision detection.